# Export careers / developer story in Word docx format

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

Since every company you apply for or recruiter wants the CV in Microsoft Word (docx) format, it would nice to have the option to export the Careers / Developer Story profile page to Microsoft Word too, in addition to PDF ...

Comment: Still no answer?  This is a very good feature request!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you export StackOverflow Developer Story data?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416702/how-do-you-export-stackoverflow-developer-story-data). Now that the dev story is being sunset, let's consolidate export requests in one place