# How do you export Stack Overflow Developer Story data?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

[Developer Story is sunsetting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story) on **Apr 1, 2022**. I'd like to know all the ways to export my data. I realize there's the PDF export, but you lose certain data, like the Pluralsight assessments, for example. Are there any other options to export all data?

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for a [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com) post, btw

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I've come across while parsing the various discussions around sunsetting SO Developer Story:

1. [devstory.fyi](https://devstory.fyi/users/story/preview?utm_campaign=launch&utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=social) (Full disclosure: I created this and announced it on [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/9354/export-so-developer-story-to-devstory-fyi))
2. [developerstory.dev](https://developerstory.dev/)

I've seen mentions of an alternative CV platform as well, not really exporting from SO, but may be of interest:

1. [flowcv.io](https://flowcv.io/)

Comment: Here are another alternative: https://www.getmanfred.com/stackoverflowgeddon

Comment: Alternative open source solution, thanks to https://getmanfred.com/stackoverflowgeddon  you can check here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416892/1654688